# Including text in the middle of group plot object

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to include a \vdots in the middle of a group plot, and for that, I'm trying to insert a plot with no bounding axis, but haven't been able to do so.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={auto, text=blue}]
    \begin{groupplot}[          
    group style=
        {group size=1 by 4,
        vertical sep=0pt,
        group name = myplots},
        height=2cm,
        width=5cm,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        ] 
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[blue, title=Multichannel Audio] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate (ax1);
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[red] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate[near start] (ax2) ;
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[hide axis, draw=none, no markers, axis line style={draw=none}, 
         tick style={draw=none}] {0} node[midway, draw=none, align=center] (ax3) {$\vdots$};
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[green] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate[near start] (ax2) ;
        \end{groupplot}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: badplot]

Between the red and green plot, I wish to have a \vdots, to represent multiple channels,  without the bounding box in the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after tinkering I've found a way:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={auto, text=blue}]
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style=
            {group size=1 by 4,
                vertical sep=0pt,
                group name = myplots},
            height=2cm,
            width=5cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[blue, title=Multichannel Audio] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate (ax1);
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[red] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate[near start] (ax2) ;
            \nextgroupplot[hide axis, draw=none, no markers, axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none}]
            \addplot[white] {0} node[black, midway, draw=none, align=center, yshift=3] (ax3) {$\vdots$};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[green] table [col sep=comma] {audio1.csv} coordinate[near start] (ax2) ;
            
        \end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This lead to the following image:

[image: correct plot]

Which was what I was trying to accomplish.